Organise n circles of varying radii inside a circle in the tightest possible way
I have an interesting problem which I have been dealing with for a couple of weeks now. I am trying to organise a known amount of circles of VARYING radius inside a circle. I have searched through all of the Wikipedia pages as well as on here and throughout the internet and I cannot find an answer of an optimal way to solve this!
I want to create a piece of software such that a user can type in the amount of circles of each radius which he has and he can obtain a solution for arranging them in the tightest possible way, as well as the radius of the 'envelope' circle.
I found some useful information in the following page:
Position N circles of different radii inside a larger circle without overlapping
and I have tried a similar algorithm which has been recommended (I made circles gravitate instead of charged which is the same physical principle). I am now in the process of generating circles in a spiral and then collecting them together with a 'trap circle' which closes in on them and collects them. I am not sure if this is the best algorithm and I am sure that there is some clever way to make this more efficient. I am getting fairly close with this approach but it is still not the tightest solution.
One thing which my research and time on this has made me sure of though is that this is a non trivial problem and there is no recipe for success on every single situation. Sometimes we want the largest circles on the inside whereas sometimes we want a small circle inside. Does anyone have any ideas on any algorithms I can use to calculate the solution more efficiently?
